# Post request if user close tab, Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I try to make post request if user try to close tab or change route. But I get null value for one variable.

```
detectTabClose() {
  let newValues = {
    question: this.question_id,
    user_id: this.$userId  //this is global, from root and is ok
  };

  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e) {
    var confirmationMessage = "o/";
    (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage;

    console.log(this.question_id);  //I get undefined
    axios
      .post("/submit/answer", newValues)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Post before tab closing");
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log("Error on post");
      });

    return confirmationMessage;
  });
},
```

Comment: What variable are you getting null? When do you call detectTabClose?

Comment: In called in created. this.question_id is null. The post is made when I try to close tab, but that var is null.

Comment: Seems like you are calling this function before `this.question_id` is initialized. Try to call it after it has been initialized with data, or insert that json creation into your listener

Comment: It's called after the page is render, and the question_id is set. The thing is that inside this method I can't access var / methods from VueJs.

Comment: Note the usage of this in your case https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you cannot access to `this.question_id` inside the `window.addEventListener` is that you're not using an arrow function. In your case right now, `this` keyword points to the event instead of vue instance.

If you use this arrow function for listener event, you can access the `question_id`.

```
detectTabClose() {
  let newValues = {
    question: this.question_id,
    user_id: this.$userId  //this is global, from root and is ok
  };

  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (e) => {
    var confirmationMessage = "o/";
    (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage;

    console.log(this.question_id);  // this will be accessible now
    axios
      .post("/submit/answer", newValues)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Post before tab closing");
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log("Error on post");
      });

    return confirmationMessage;
  });
},
```